Numerically solving Pontryagin's Maximum Principle
I am trying to understand why when solving this boundary problem in matlab is significantly impacted by the $A_0$ matrix.
The optimal control problem I am trying to solve reads:
$$
    \begin{aligned}
    \min _{u} &  
\int_0^{T}x(t)^{\top} Q x(t) +u^{\top}(t) R u(t) d t\\
         & \text{s.t.}
            \begin{array}{rl}
\dot{x}(t):=\left(A_0+A_b(x(t))\right) x(t)+Bu(t), x(0)=x_0,
\end{array}
    \end{aligned}
$$
which results in the following two-point boundary value problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{d}{d t} x^*(t)=\left(A_0+A_b(x^{*}(t))\right) x^{*}(t)+B u^{*}(t), \\
x^*(0)=x_0, \\
-\frac{d \lambda^{*}(t)}{dt} = 2Qx^{*}(t) + \left(A_0^{\top} + \begin{bmatrix}
    x^{*\top}(t)(A_1 + A_1^{\top})\\
    \vdots\\
    x^{*\top}(t)(A_N + A_N^{\top})\\
\end{bmatrix} \right)\lambda(t)^{*} \\
\lambda^{*}(T)=0, \\
u^*(t)=-\frac{1}{2} R^{-1} B^{\top} \lambda^*(t).
\end{array}\right.
$$
Here $A_{b}(x(t))=\begin{bmatrix}
x(t)^{\top} A_1\\ \vdots\\x(t)^{\top} A_N\end{bmatrix}.$
Let $N=5$, when $A_0 = diag(-0.2,-0.8,-1.8,-3.2,-5.0)$ I could solve the problem easily with forward and backward integration with the step size $0.1$. However, when $A_0 = diag(-0.03,-0.12,-0.27,-0.48,-0.75)$, I need to significantly reduce the step size, e.g. to $0.001$, and the program might not be stable for some initial conditions.
I am really curious if this observation is because of the stiffness of the system, or the nature of first order optimization method for nonconvex optimization. After modifying the forward and backward integration with an extra Nesterov momentum step, the program is getting much more stable. However, it results in more computational efforts.
Overall questions: (1) Why the program solving the two-point boundary value problem is not stable for some $A_0$? (2) How can I solve this problem in an efficient and stable way?
Thanks in advance!
In the following, you can find my Matlab code.
clear all
close all
clc

N=5;

A = zeros(N,N,N);

A(:,:,1) = [
    0    1.0000    0    0    0;
   -0.5000    0    1.5000    0    0;
    0   -1.0000    0    2.0000    0;
    0    0   -1.5000    0    2.5000;
    0    0    0   -2.0000    0];

A(:,:,2) = [
   -0.5000    0    1.5000    0    0;
    0    0    0    2.0000    0;
   -0.5000    0    0    0    2.5000;
    0   -1.0000    0    0    0;
    0    0   -1.5000    0    0];

A(:,:,3) = [
    0   -1.0000    0    2.0000    0;
   -0.5000    0    0    0    2.5000;
    0    0    0    0    0;
   -0.5000    0    0    0    0;
    0   -1.0000    0    0    0];

A(:,:,4) = [
    0    0   -1.5000    0    2.5000;
    0   -1.0000    0    0    0;
   -0.5000    0    0    0    0;
    0    0    0    0    0;
   -0.5000    0    0    0    0];

A(:,:,5) = [
    0    0    0   -2.0000    0;
    0    0   -1.5000    0    0;
    0   -1.0000    0    0    0;
   -0.5000    0    0    0    0;
    0    0    0    0    0];



% nu = 0.03
% K = [
%    -0.0300   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000;
%    -0.0000   -0.1200    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000;
%    -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.2700    0.0000    0.0000;
%    -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.4800    0.0000;
%     0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.7500];

% % nu = 0.2
K = [
   -0.2000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000;
    0.0000   -0.8000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000;
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -1.8000   -0.0000    0.0000;
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -3.2000   -0.0000;
    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -5.0000];


B =[0.2021;
    0.3629;
    0.4523;
    0.4589;
    0.3929];

Q = [
    1.5708    0         0         0         0;
    0         1.5708    0         0         0;
    0         0         1.5708    0         0;
    0         0         0         1.5708    0;
    0         0         0         0         1.5708];

R = [1];

rhoinit=zeros(N,1);
rhoinit(1,1)=5.;
rhoinit(2,1)=5.;
rhoinit(3,1)=5.;
rhoinit(4,1)=5.;

rho_zero = zeros(N,1);


dt=0:0.01:10;
dt_inv = 10:-0.01:0;

lambda0_target = zeros(N, 1);

T=zeros(N,N);
T=squeeze(pagemtimes(rho_zero',A));

[F,P,~]=lqr(K+T',B,Q,R);

inv_R = inv(R);

% Get initial guess of input traj using LQR
opts = odeset('RelTol',1e-6,'AbsTol',1e-12);
[Tlqr,Ulqr]=ode15s(@(t,x) burgers_lqr(K,A,B,R,P,x,t),dt, rhoinit, opts);
Ulqr = Ulqr';
lambda_list = [];
input_list = [];
for j = 1:size(Ulqr, 2)
    [~, uk, lambda] = burgers_lqr(K,A,B,R,P,Ulqr(:,j),dt(j));
    input_list = [input_list, uk];
    lambda_list = [lambda_list, lambda];
end
U = Ulqr;


eps = 1e-5;
sigma = 1e-1;
iter = 1;
while 1
    [T,U] = ode15s(@(t,state) dynamics_PMP_decoupled_state(t, K, A, B, Q, R, state, Tlqr, input_list), dt, rhoinit, opts);
    dt_temp = T;
    state_list = U';
    lambda_last = lambda0_target;
    [T,U]=ode15s(@(t,lambda) dynamics_PMP_decoupled_costate(t, K, A, B, Q, R, lambda, dt_temp, state_list), dt_inv, lambda_last, opts);
    dt_temp = fliplr(T')';
    U=U';
    lambda_list = fliplr(U);
    dH_da = 2 * R * input_list + B' * lambda_list
    if i == 1
        dH_da_prev = dH_da;
    end
    
    if max(abs(dH_da)) <= eps
        break
    else
        input_list = input_list - sigma * dH_da;
    end
    
    iter = iter + 1;
end

[T,U] = ode15s(@(t,state) dynamics_PMP_decoupled_state(t,K, A, B, Q, R, state, Tlqr, input_list), dt, rhoinit, opts);
U=U';


figure;
subplot(2, 1, 1);
hold on;
for i = 1:N
    plot(dt, U(i, :), 'DisplayName', sprintf('State Variable x_%d', i));
end
legend;
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('State Variables');
title('State Variables Solution');
hold off;

subplot(2, 1, 2);
hold on;
for i = 1:N
    plot(dt, lambda_list(i, :), 'DisplayName', sprintf('Costate Variable \lambda_%d', i));
end
legend;
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Costate Variables');
title('Costate Variables Solution');
hold off;

function [val, uk, lambda]=burgers_lqr(K,A,B,R,P,rho,t)
    
    N = size(K,1);
    T = zeros(N,N);
    
    T=squeeze(pagemtimes(rho',A));
    
    inv_R = inv(R);
    
    v0_jac = 2 * P * rho;
    
    % Control law
    uk = -0.5 * inv_R * B' * v0_jac;
    lambda = v0_jac;
    val=(K+T')*rho + B*uk;

end


function [val]=dynamics_PMP_decoupled_costate(time,K,A,B,Q,R,lambda, t_forward, state)
    N = size(K,1);
    T=zeros(N,N);
    state_interp = interp1(t_forward, state', time);
    state_interp = state_interp';    
    T=squeeze(pagemtimes(state_interp',A));
    A_transposed = permute(A, [2, 1, 3]);
    T_transposed = squeeze(pagemtimes(state_interp', A_transposed));
    dlambdadt = -(2 * Q * state_interp + (K'+T_transposed'+T') * lambda);
    val = [dlambdadt];

end

function [val]=dynamics_PMP_decoupled_state(time,K,A,B,Q,R,state, t_forward, input)
    N = size(K,1);
    T=zeros(N,N);
    input_interp =  interp1(t_forward, input', time);
    input_interp = input_interp';
    T=squeeze(pagemtimes(state',A));
    dxdt=(K+T')*state + B * input_interp;
    val = [dxdt];
end



you should try to solve this using bvp4c. Why have you not done so?

I tried bvp4c or 5c to solve the joint dynamics. However, they are not working well for my problem in high dimensions. The real dimension could be up to 100.
